# C# Random Port UDP

Tags: c#, udp

Есть код

```
namespace UDPChat
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static IPAddress _remoteIpAddress;
        private static int _remotePort;
        private static Random _rnd = new Random();
        private static int _localPort;
        private static List<string> _message = new List<string>();


        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введити: IP: Port: Сообщение: ");
                string datagramIpPort = Console.ReadLine();
                string[] messageSplit = datagramIpPort.Split(new Char[] {':'});

                foreach (string messageDate in messageSplit)
                {
                    if (messageDate.Trim() != "")
                    {
                        _message.Add(messageDate);
                    }


                    _localPort = Convert.ToInt16(_rnd.Next(49125, 65535));
                    _remoteIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse(_message[0]);
                    _remotePort = Convert.ToInt16(_message[1]);


                    Thread recieverThread = new Thread(Reciever);
                    recieverThread.Start();

                    Sender();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Возникло исключение: {e.ToString()}\n{e.Message}");
            }
        }

        private static void Sender()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string datagram = _message[2];

                UdpClient sender = new UdpClient();
                IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(_remoteIpAddress, _remotePort);

                try
                {
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(datagram); // конвертируем в байты сообщение
                    sender.Send(bytes, bytes.Length,
                        endPoint); // передаём: само сообщение, размер сообщения, удолённый Ip и удалённый Port
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Возникло исключение: {e.ToString()}\n{e.Message}");
                }
                finally
                {
                    sender.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Reciever()
        {
            UdpClient recievingUdpClient = new UdpClient(_localPort);
            IPEndPoint remotEndPoint = null;
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    byte[] recievingBytes = recievingUdpClient.Receive(ref remotEndPoint);
                    string returnDate = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recievingBytes);
                    Console.WriteLine($">>> {returnDate}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Возникло исключение: {e.ToString()}\n{e.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно что бы рандомно выдавал локальный порт. Выдаёт ошибку

```
Введити: IP: Port: Сообщение:
127.0.0.1:5000:Hello
Возникло исключение: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции.
Имя параметра: index
   в System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   в System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   в UDPChat.Program.Main(String[] args) в D:\MailCloud#NOUT\C#\Rider_Project_JetBrains_C#\UDPChat_lesson_44\UDPChat\Program.cs:строка 39
Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции.
Имя параметра: index
```

Проблема вроде в конвертации в строке 36, но не могу понять как решить!

Comment: Может быть тут `_remotePort = Convert.ToInt16(_message[1]);` тоже стоит обновить до 32?

Comment: @Anamnian Пробовал тоже самое! Проблема с List теперь по мойму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам же явно говорит ошибка, что для `int16` ваше число очень большое!
`int16` вмещает в себя [От -32 768 до 32 767](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/short).

Теперь посмотрим внимательней: `Convert.ToInt16(_rnd.Next(49125, 65535));`, вы пытаетесь засунуть туда случайное число от 49125 до 65535.

Решение: Использовать что то более вместительное, например [Int32](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int).

Comment: Хотя нужно спросить автора- возможно у него были причины использовать Int16

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Теперь выдаёт: `Введити: IP: Port: Сообщение:
127.0.0.1:5000:Hello
Возникло исключение: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции.
Имя параметра: index
   в System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   в System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   в UDPChat.Program.Main(String[] args) в D:\MailCloud#NOUT\C#\Rider_Project_JetBrains_C#\UDPChat_lesson_44\UDPChat\Program.cs:строка 39`
`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Заменил на ToInt32

Comment: @Anamnian Вообще вроде для портов нужно использовать ToInt16 почему не знаю. Но по заданию мне нужно рандом из диапазона который в примере.

Comment: @j.Atisto откуда вы это взяли? Можно ссылку на источник?

Comment: @Anamnian На лекции говорили. Может не так понял.

Comment: [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_портов_TCP_и_UDP): Количество портов ограничено с учётом 16-битной адресации (2 в 16=65536, начало — «0»). В c# только int32 и выше может принимать 65535. Что касательно ошибки, то 1. Не хорошо в одном вопросе задавать сразу два. 2. Посмотрите, что у вас в `List<string> _message`, сколько там значений и какие. Я на 99% уверен, что их там два (а то и одно), когда вы требуете у коллекции явно 3 значения. P.S. Вы используете не очень хороших подход с использованием коллекции. Используйте класс с необходимыми полями (порт, сообщение, адрес).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  на счёт подхода вы правы, но для данного задания, мне не нужно создавать новый класс. И проблема была в фигурной скобке в цикле. Теперь всё работает но при вводе сообщения в формате 127.0.0.1:5000:Hello ошибок нет, но программа ожидает чего то. Не могу понять чего! Не подскажете?

Comment: @j.Atisto Вы знаете. что такое Debug? Пройдитесь им шаг за шагом по каждой строчке кода и посмотрите работу логики, найдете место, где "тормозит" прям в миг! А я к сожалению вам с этим не помогу, ибо с TCP/UDP не сильно не знаком...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да вот тоже самое! Как раз Дебажу! Спасибо!

Comment: @j.Atisto Скорей всего проблема у вас в `while (true)` цикле, он бесконечно инициализирует клиент и делает всю внутреннюю логику без выхода, это не правильно!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: А что насчет `Uint16`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.uint16.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx там дмапазон как раз то самое максимальное число что и у порта. думаю лучше использовать его а не `Int32`

Comment: @LLENN Можно по сути и его использовать, все зависит от целей автора. Лично мне привычней использовать обычный int. Но если автор занимается ярой оптимизацией, то да, Uint16 (ushort) лучше.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (messageDate.Trim() != "")
{
    _message.Add(messageDate);
}


_localPort = Convert.ToInt32(_rnd.Next(49125, 65535));
_remoteIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse(_message[0]);
_remotePort = Convert.ToInt16(_message[1]);
```

Давайте повнимательней рассмотрим этот кусок кода- на первой итерации вы кладете в пустой лист `_message` одно сообщение, и позже запрашиваете 1 и 2 сообщение из этого списка. Так как у вас там всего одно сообщение, то и генерируется исключение "Индекс за пределами диапазона значений".

И лучше не изменять код вопроса при появлении другой ошибки, а дополнять его (или вообще задать новый вопрос). Так как ответ [@EvgeniyZ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/877781/218976) был абсолютно правильным и решил вашу проблему с первым исключением.

UPD: Постараюсь более подробно объяснить:

```
private static List<string> _message = new List<string>();
```

Изначально в списке 0 строк. Во время выполнения цикла в первой итерации вы записываете в `_message` 1 строку `_message.Add(messageDate);`.

Потом 3 строки кода спустя вы обращаетесь к этому списку и хотите получить `_message[1]`, где и генерируется данное исключение`_message` только 1 строка- вы можете это посмотреть под отладкой, поставив точку остановки на эту строчку и наведя мышью на данную переменную.

Comment: Про изменение в вопросе, вы правы не подумал. А, по поводу итерации  не понял. Что я делаю то не так!

Comment: @j.Atisto Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Проблема была в `{` фигурной скобке в цикле foreach